# Telegram bot: loop on database query

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a simple bot (I am using webhook) that responds to a command and goes to the database and sends a sticker and a simple html message for every record found.

If there are many records (20 or more AND took more than 2 minutes to finish the while bucle) bot goes crazy and display the results 4 times (finish one time and then starts again 3 more times), I tried to add a sleep() timer to avoid the loop but have no luck. Not sure what I am missing or doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if (isset($update->message)){

//Fetching update
$message = $update->message;
$message_id = $update->message->message_id;
$text = $message->text;
$chat_id = $message->chat->id;

    switch($text){     
    case "read":
        $age = 18;
        read_fields($age, $chat_id);
        break;

    default:
        bot('SendMessage',[
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => "This is a test"
        ]);
    }
}

function read_fields($age, $chat_id){
    include("conexion.inc");

    $i = 0; 
    $sticker = "";
    $id = "";
    $name = "";

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, sticker FROM Persons WHERE age =  ".$age;
    $php = mysql_query($sql, $con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($php)){

        $sticker = $row['id_sticker']; 
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name']; 

        bot('sendSticker',[
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'sticker' => $id_sticker
        ]);

        $message = $id."-<b>".$name."</b>";

        bot('SendMessage',[
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'parse_mode' => "HTML",
            'text' => $mensaje
        ]); 

        sleep(3);

        $i++;
    }

    bot('SendMessage',[
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => "### ".$i." total ### "
   ]);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram Bot API will retry webhook request when server-side consider there are dropped, so you need to reduce response time.

One solution is process them quickly, but it seems not easy.

If you know how to close HTTP connection before timeout, just do that, since it's implement is different from your HTTP server, try to search like `NginX fastcgi close upstream connection`.

Comment: so, I could try to make it faster displaying by ranges of data.
I mean, if I have 50 records, I could call the read_fields function 3 times and display 20, 20, and 10 respectively. 
Now question is, how can I pass that range to the query?